# Event continuing before dialog answer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The user in the dialog is being asked a Yes or No, so the dialog is returning true/false. This is an mdDialog.

If the args.cancel is true, it will navigate, if its false it won't. However it is continuing before the args.cancel has been given a value (it defaults to true)

This is a problem because the actual navigation is being done else where I just want to tell it to stop if the user tells it to stop.

Basically its asynchronous but I need it to be synchronous

```
function onNavigation(args) { // this will trigger when view is changed{

    SaveDialog(function(answer) {
        args.cancel = answer;
    })

}
```

The MdDialog code

```
spmApp.controller('SaveController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', 'spmWebAPI', 'tasks', 'resources', function($scope, $mdDialog, spmWebAPI, tasks, resources) {

    $scope.closeDialog = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide(false);
    }
    $scope.Save = function() {

        $mdDialog.hide(true);

    }
}]);
```